# Is it possible to define a Cloudformation Resource in-place?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a resource definition

```
APITaskDefinition:
  Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
  Properties:
    ...
    ExecutionRoleArn:
      <RoleADefinition here>
    ...
    TaskRoleArn:
      <RoleBDefinition here>
    ...
```

This would be great given these roles are only going to be used by this resoure `APITaskDefinition` and is considered best practice to use a specific role for each resource which is going to require one

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe we can do that with CloudFormation.

Standard practice is to define all the resources together in single template and refer it.

```
  EcsTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ecs-taskExecution
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
                  - 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability'
                  - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
                  - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: '*'
```

and !GetAtt EcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn

```
      ContainerTaskdefinition:
        Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
        Properties:
          Family: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
          ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt EcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn <-- refer to task Arn
          TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt EcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn <-- refer to task Arn
          Cpu: '256'
          Memory: 1GB
          NetworkMode: awsvpc
          RequiresCompatibilities:
            - EC2
            - FARGATE
          ContainerDefinitions:
            - Name: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              Cpu: 10
              Essential: 'true'
              Image: !Ref Image
              Memory: '1024'
```

However, with AWS CDK, we can use a higher level construct which creates the roles with default permissions in most cases and can easily add additional permissions needed, when compiled creates the above cloudformation. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html) is ECS Construct